# z-index not functioning properly on menu, due to jQuery slider

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

It appears that for some reason my content slider sits "on top" of my navigation menu despite my adjustment of various z-index properties to correct the issue.

The wrapper on my menu is a positionable element and the slider is only setting the content to z-index's of 98 or 99 so I can't quite figure out why setting my menu to a z-index of 999 doesn't work.

I've tried adjusting the various z-indexes via Firebug to no avail.

The site in question currently resides on our test server here: http://www.testflightapparel.com

Comment: Post your HTML CSS please , it will be helpful.

Comment: I think viewing the source in your browser, or better yet using a plugin dedicated to this sort of debugging like Firebug is much more suitable to this particular issue due to the complexity of the HTML/CSS involved. The CSS alone is 1400 lines. Since I am unsure where I need to adjust the property I don't know how much of this huge chunk of code to include. Usually I'm pretty good with CSS, but this issue really eludes me. I'm wondering if it is related to the slider styling being in-line.

Comment: No issues I hope you are aware that z-index only work when the element is positioned to absolute or relative.Pls check if the slider which sits on top is positioned.

Comment: Yes the slider uses absolute positioning and z-indexes of 98 or 99. The menu has a position:relative tacked onto it's parent element.

Comment: try positioning your menu to `absolute`, then use z-index to force it on top.

Comment: Yeah I tried that before posting this Dexter.

I believe my initial diagnoses may have been wrong. The two elements stack vertically so I assumed that when the dropdown menu from the top element (menu) dropped down over the bottom one (content slider) it was being rendered behind the slider, however it looks like the issue may actually be related to my overflow visibility, which would explain all of my confusion.

Comment: Looks like I was *partially* correct. The overflow was hiding the content, but now that I know it is being rendered in the correct  place, the z-index is still off.

Comment: @ColtMcCormack Try to render your menu right after the slider... so it would be forced to be rendered on top. Just use negative margin-top to position it above the slider. I already tried editing your HTML in Chrome and it worked.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just setting the z-index on the slider to -1 instead, which finally worked after the overflow issue was fixed. Seemed to be a bit cleaner than having the elements getting pushed around in funny ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Usually `position: absolute;` along with `z-index` works always in my projects with sliders. Do not forget to render the menu **after** the slider so it is forced to sit on **top**.

Here is what I did when I edited your HTML in Chrome:

```
<div class="main">
...
 your slider code
...
</div>

<!--See the added inline styles -->

<div class="wrapper_menu menu_dark_theme" style="position: absolute; margin-top: -1200px; z-index: 9999;">
   <ul class="menu menu_takeflight">...</ul>
</div>
```

See screen capture attached: