# Slider & Menu z-index issue positioning

Tags: jquery, css, html, z-index, positioning

I have a bug with the flexslider and menu positioning/z-index.
I have read several topics here about changing z-index, changing overflow:hidden to float:left.
But none of this is working.

The only thing i have not tried is making the html with slider first, then menu and margin negative
e.g. [z-index not functioning properly on menu, due to jQuery slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409303/z-index-not-functioning-properly-on-menu-due-to-jquery-slider)

But i would like to keep my order of structure on a normal and logic way.

Link : http://hvweb.be/client/voiment/index.html

Best regards,
Hannes Verbrugghe
contact@hvweb.be

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to solve this by giving the slider a lower z-index.

```
#slider {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: thx ! My slider div tag didnt had any value in the css. That's why it was bugged.